# Asp object won't except null passed from database

Tags: vb.net, asp-classic

This code works fine when there is a entry in the database, however when I remove the entry it errors out. I believe it's not taking in a null value. I don't really work asp but I would really like to understand how to make it work if there is no value in the database

```
<%
Dim rsValue

gParama = "^Param1^,^Param2^"
set rsValue = GetData(000, gParama,"","")
sURL= rsValue("table column")
rsValue = nothing
%>

<html>
 .......
<% if sURL <> "" then %>
   <td>
  <a href=<%sURL%> class="user">
 <img src= "../images/random.gif" > RANDOM</a>
  </td>
 <%end if%>
 .......
 </html>
```

Comment: The error is inside GetData I presume? Does that piece of code check for recordset.eof before retrieving the value?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for EOF (end of file) before using your recordset.

```
if rsValue.eof then
    'no data!
end of
```